# Run one or the other task based on variable existence

Tags: ansible

I am writing ansible playbooks and part of the tasks i am trying to achieve is to fetch a file from `get_url` module.

This playbook needs to run in an environment where a proxy is mandatory, and in another environment where there is no proxy (i.e. the fetch of the file is direct).

I have been struggling with my code to make it consistent, here it is.
Note: I alternatively have the variable defined case#1 and undefined case#2

group_vars/all:

```
---
proxy_env:
  http_proxy: <<i enter my proxy here>>
```

test.yml:

```
---
- hosts: control_nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Downloading file through proxy
      get_url:
        url=http://address-that-requires-proxy/file_thru_proxy.txt dest=/root/file_thru_proxy.txt force=yes use_proxy=yes
        when: proxy_env.http_proxy is defined
    - name: Downloading file not through proxy
      get_url:
        url=http://address-that-DOESNOT-require-proxy/file_not_thru_proxy.txt dest=/root/file_not_thru_proxy.txt force=yes
        when: proxy_env.http_proxy is undefined
environment:
  http_proxy: "{{ proxy_env.http_proxy }}"
```

Case#1: proxy_env.http_proxy in group_vars/all is defined, all is fine:

```
[root@blade8 my_playbooks]# ansible-playbook -i hosts -s test.yml 
...
ok: [blade1]
TASK: [Downloading file through proxy] ************************* 
ok: [blade1]
TASK: [Downloading file not through proxy] ********************* 
skipping: [blade1]
...
```

Case#2: proxy_env.http_proxy in group_vars/all is NOT defined (it is commented), it fails:

```
[root@blade8 my_playbooks]# ansible-playbook -i hosts -s test.yml 
...
TASK: [Downloading file through proxy] ************************* 
skipping: [blade1]
TASK: [Downloading file not through proxy] ********************* 
failed: [blade1] => {"dest": "/root/file_not_thru_proxy.txt", "failed": true, "response": "Request failed: <urlopen error [Errno -2] Name or service not known>", "state": "absent", "status_code": -1, "url": "http://address-that-DOESNOT-require-proxy/file_not_thru_proxy.txt"}
msg: Request failed
...
```

the first task is skipped because the variable is undefined. but the second one should work, because i can download it with a simple wget command.

Any idea, what is going on? Or any suggestion to implement it better?

Comment: You sure this code does not throw errors? I see 3 indention errors (both `when` lines and the `environment ` block) which should prevent playbook execution.

Comment: Also I'm not sure what problem you're describing. Your title reads like you have problems with conditionals. But that seems to be not the case, right? Your problem seems to simply be the `get_url` module results in "Request failed"? You better should reduce your question to the exact problem, which seems to be the host can not be resolved.

Answer (score 1):

The problem might be that you set the http_proxy on your playbook level. So it is set even if it is not defined in your group_vars. This might still result in get_url trying to fetch the url through an undefined proxy... no idea but worth trying:

```
---
- hosts: control_nodes
  tasks:
    - name: Downloading file through proxy
      get_url:
        url: http://address-that-requires-proxy/file_thru_proxy.txt
        dest: /root/file_thru_proxy.txt
        force: yes
        use_proxy: yes
      when: "http_proxy" in proxy_env
      environment:
        http_proxy: "{{ proxy_env.http_proxy }}"
    - name: Downloading file not through proxy
      get_url:
        url: http://address-that-DOESNOT-require-proxy/file_not_thru_proxy.txt
        dest: /root/file_not_thru_proxy.txt
        force: yes
      when: "http_proxy" not in proxy_env
```